# Hibernate - createNativeQuery with "non-entity class" result

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to all this Hibernate/JPA stuff, so i will try to be as clear as possible.

Is there any way in Hibernate to use createNativeQuery to select a single/or multiple fields in a query without using an Entity class as the return object ?

I'm trying to do this without using any XML related stuff.

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select name from contact where id_contact = :idContact", String.class);
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
Object string = query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println(string);
```

Using this i have the Exception : `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.String`

Thanks

Edit :

I also tried :

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select name from contact where id_contact = :idContact");
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
List list = query.getResultList();
if (!list.isEmpty()){ 
    Object string = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

With the same Exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Edit (2) : 
I'm starting to think it's either a bug in Hibernate or it's impossible to do such things...

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that you are passing `String.class` as the second parameter to `createNativeQuery`. This will make hibernate attempt to use the `String.class` to create a mapping for the result set. It can only create this mapping from entity classes and `String` is not an entity class because it isn't mapped to a table.

Fortunately, the solution is to simply use an overloaded version of `createNativeQuery` that doesn't require a second parameter.

```
String SQL = ".."; //same SQL as you had before
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SQL); //no entity mapping
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
Object string = query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 7):

In case of Native query or jpql with column name EntityManager Returns a List of array of objects.

so to get Result List.

receive it in a

```
 List<Object[]> listResults = query.getResultList();
```

then iterate over it:-

```
for (Object[] record : listResults) {

            //Iterate Logic will come here

                    }
```

Comment: listResults is a list of Object[] so you need to Iterate over the Object[] in order to get your data

Answer (score 4):

Just try to call `createNativeQuery()` without passing `String.class`. If the `name` column is of string-type in database `query.getSingleResult()` will actually return a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String SQL = ".."; //same SQL as you had before
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SQL); //no entity mapping
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
String string = (String)query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

For Hibernate 5.0

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Object[]> objects = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(objects.get(0)[0]);
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/native/Native.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select name from contact where id_contact = :idContact", String.class);
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
List list = query.getResultList();
if (!list.isEmpty()){ 
    Object string = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

In the Look here

http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa

Comment: Same exception thrown : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;