# JPA: Perform a query on multiple tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Im new to using JPA in java and im curious how to perform a multi table query using JPA.  I understand you create a class that is designated as an entity to represent objects in a database however if I want to do advanced multi table queries using @query do I need to create a second class to represent the other table as an entity?

For example a single @query

```
@Query("select * from Stores")
```

Where Stores is a table in my database that also has an associated entity class in my code.

I want to do something like
@Query("select * from Stores, Owner where Store.id = Owner.id)
where Owner is just a table in a database and does not have an associated entity

All help is appreciated.

Comment: createNativeQuery - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051058/hibernate-createnativequery-with-non-entity-class-result

Comment: If you want to use JPQL, you need your model to be represented as entities that are mapped to tables (not always 1:1). JPQL doesn't care for/know about tables so you can't directly access tables there. As Scary Wombat suggested you can execute native queries via the entity manager but in that case you're operating entirely on tables and not on entities anymore.

Comment: Instead of thinking about tables and queries, I highly recommend thinking of JPA as some kind of black box. Define your classes (Store, Owner) and define (using JPA annotations) how the fields are  used to connect these classes. Then, just ask JPA for the Store objects. Depending on how you annotated the field, the owner details are already included or will be retrieved from the DB on demand.