# How to run a Hibernate NativeQuery in a type-safe manner instead of returning an Object[]

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm migrating an application from Hibernate 4.x to Hibernate 5.3.6. The application has queries like this:

```
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable");
```

As the method [createSQLQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-) has been deprecated, I first replaced the method call with the alternative suggested in the Hibernate Javadoc, namely using createNativeQuery:

```
NativeQuery query = getSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable");
```

The problem with this is that it produces a compiler warning "NativeQuery is a raw type. References to generic type NativeQuery should be parameterized". Furthermore, of course I'd like to benefit from typed queries, now that they are available. So I changed the query to

```
NativeQuery<Object[]> query = getSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable", Object[].class);
```

Now the problem is that executing the query with

```
List<Object[]> retList = query.list();
```

produces the error

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Ljava.lang.Object;

Researching the problem [seems to indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19051238/76777) that it is not possible to use non-mapped entities when using typed native queries (which seems like a serious and unnecessary restriction, but I digress here).

**The question:** is there any way *to* execute a native SQL query returning an array of Objects using Hibernate *without* producing compiler warnings *while* achieving type safety? If not, is there any sensible alternative?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are much better alternatives for such projections instead of the default `Object[]`.

1. You could use the JPA [`javax.persistence.Tuple`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) result set which, since [Hibernate ORM 5.2.11](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11897) works for native SQL:

   ```
    List<Tuple> postDTOs = entityManager
    .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT " +
        "       p.id AS id, " +
        "       p.title AS title " +
        "FROM Post p " +
        "WHERE p.created_on > :fromTimestamp", Tuple.class)
    .setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
        LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
            .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
    .getResultList();
   ```
2. You could use the Hibernate-specific [`ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/) which allows you to build very complex DTO structures (e.g. graphs):

   ```
    List postDTOs = entityManager
    .createNativeQuery(
        "select " +
        "       p.id as \"id\", " +
        "       p.title as \"title\" " +
        "from Post p " +
        "where p.created_on > :fromTimestamp")
    .setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
        LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ).toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
    .unwrap( org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class )
    .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PostDTO.class ) )
    .getResultList();
   ```
3. You could also use a named native query:

   ```
    List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("PostDTO")
    .setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
        LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
            .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
    .getResultList();
   ```

   where the `PostDTO` query is a named native SQL query that looks as follows:

   ```
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "PostDTO",
        query =
            "SELECT " +
            "       p.id AS id, " +
            "       p.title AS title " +
            "FROM Post p " +
            "WHERE p.created_on > :fromTimestamp",
        resultSetMapping = "PostDTO"
    )
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "PostDTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = PostDTO.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "title")
            }
        )
    )
   ```

Cool, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just create it with the call

```
createNativeQuery("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable");
```

and it will default to returning a rows of `Object[]`.

The warning is irrelevant for your case, so just suppress it.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, is there any sensible alternative?

Since you're asking for alternatives (probably including ones that don't involve Hibernate), I think it's fair to mention [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) here, where you would write your query like this:

```java
Result<Record3<Integer, String, Long>> result =
ctx.select(A.A, A.B, A.C)
   .from(A)
   .fetch();
```

Denoting generics can be avoided with just `var`:

```java
var result =
ctx.select(A.A, A.B, A.C)
   .from(A)
   .fetch();
```

Or, if you want to continue using the string version of your query, you can access with a bit less type safety, using conversions:

```java
Result<?> result = ctx.fetch("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable");
for (Record record : result) {
    int a = record.get(0, int.class);
    String b = record.get(1, String.class);
    long c = record.get(2, long.class);
}
```

Or, you use a DTO / POJO

```java
class POJO {
  int a;
  String b;
  long c;
}

List<POJO> list = ctx.fetch("SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c FROM aTable").into(POJO.class);
```

If your results are entities, [you can execute that query easily on an `EntityManager`, using jOOQ and Hibernate together](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/alternative-execution-models/using-jooq-with-jpa/using-jooq-with-jpa-entities/)

(Disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOQ)